# Does the complex limit $\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{\bar{z}-1}{z-1}$ exist?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Does the complex limit $\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{\bar{z}-1}{z-1}$ exist?

I am not sure how to begin with this. My guess is that it does not exist due to the fact that conjugation isn't complex differentiable? But maybe this isn't the exact reason. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not exist

Take the sequence $z_{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$, we have that $z_{n} \to 1$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\bar{z_{n}} - 1}{z_{n} - 1} = 1$

But if you take $w_{n} = 1 + \frac{i}{n}$, we have that $w_{n} \to 1$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\bar{w_{n}} - 1}{w_{n} - 1} = -1$

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce to
$$
\lim_{w\to0}\frac{\bar{w}}{w}
$$
with the substitution $w=z-1$. Now try approaching $0$ along the real axis and along the imaginary axis.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_\limits{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \frac {x-iy - 1}{x+iy-1}$

At this point, I think it might be easier if you convert to polar

$x - 1 = r\cos \theta\\
iy = ir\sin\theta$

$\lim_\limits{r\to 0} \frac {\cos\theta - i\sin\theta}{\cos\theta + i\sin \theta}$

Does this limit exist?